# Laravel: Auth::user()->ci get a incomplete string

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I want to get a String through `Auth::user()->ci`, ci is a String for example 060123456-7,
 but when I write this `Auth::user()->ci` I get an incomplete value because It gets  '60123456'.

Any ideas? Please, help me.

Comment: Show us the code where you set the value. Also show us the code where you retrieve the value.

Comment: Are you storing this value as a string or an integer? It looks like it's trimming the leading 0, which generally happens to 0-leading integers. Likely the same for the `-7` at the end.

Comment: CI is being cast as an integer. If you have verified that it is being stored correctly in the database then you may need to cast the attribute to a string, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting